# visual studio continue multiline comment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, comments

Visual Studio 2005.  Working with C++, is there a way to have it automatically continue commenting when I press Enter?  Ex, I type '//' and begin entering my long-winded comment.  When I press Enter, I want it to automatically place a '//' sequence at the current indent level (or a '*' if commenting with C-style comments).  I have not yet googled me up a solution (though it seems many folks want the C-style comment continuation removed).

Comment: try placing \ before hitting enter. Yes this is a cheat, but it gets the work done

Comment: Use /* and */ to delimit your comments, or an #if 0 ... #endif block.

Comment: I know I can use the C style comments, I like the auto-comment feature.  The \ "cheat" did not work.  I gather then, that what I am looking for does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

I've exhaustively searched the editor preferences in VS 2013, there is currently no option to auto continue a `//` comment.

However, with **triple slash (`///`) comments**, you have a couple of options:

A triple slash comment line will automatically continue after pressing `Enter` if:

1. **The comment line at the cursor contains any non-whitespace character.**  I like this condition, because I can keep typing as normal, then double-tap `Enter` to terminate the comment.  It ends up looking like this:

   ```
   /// This is my multiline comment.
   ```

   Press `Enter` and type more comment:

   ```
   /// This is my multiline comment.
   /// I just pressed enter.  Now I'll press enter twice and start coding.
   ```

   Press `Enter` twice and type code:

   ```
   /// This is my multiline comment.
   /// I just pressed enter.  Now I'll press enter twice and start coding.
   /// 
   public class ...
   ```
2. **The comment line below the cursor contains another triple slash comment.**  This allows you to have big comments with multiple paragraphs and usage examples separated by empty lines.  Here it is:

   ```
   /// There is already a comment line below. CURSOR IS HERE -> |
   ///
   ```

   Press `Enter` three times and start a usage example:

   ```
   /// There is already a comment line below. CURSOR IS HERE -> |
   ///
   ///
   /// For Example:
   /// 
   /// Foo foo = bar;
   ///
   ```

   The empty comment line remains, and you can continue commenting arbitrarily.

Comment: Hmm, not working for me in Visual Studio 2017 in a C++ project, is there an option I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

One hack is to press `Space` `Left` `Enter` when at the end of a comment. It seems to discard the extra space as well.

VS splits comments across multiple lines nicely if you press `Enter` midway through a comment, so this is tapping into that functionality.

You might be able to make a hotkey that makes `Enter` always do this in VS, as it discards the space even when not in comments.